# Prolog query: how does addition matter for recursive queries

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a predicate to find the nth element of a list.

Initially I wrote something like this:

```
nth([X|_], 0, X).
nth([_|T],N,Z):- N > 0, nth(T, M, Z), N is M + 1.
```

It works for queries such as `nth([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, X).` but for queries such as `nth([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], N, 1).`, I get an "arguments insufficiently instantiated error" after I enter ";" after getting the answer. I know that there will be only 1 ans in this case, but for the sake of completeness, I want to know why.

I read on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464504/how-to-find-the-nth-element-of-a-list-in-prolog) that the following is a better solution:

```
nth([X|_], 0, X) :- !.
nth([_|Y], N, Z) :- N > 0, M is N-1, nth(Y, M, Z).
```

I want to understand why `M is N-1, nth(Y, M, Z).` makes a difference as against the `nth(T, M, Z), N is M + 1` in my answer.

PS: I think the question title can be improved, but I'm not sure of how. If you have suggestions, please let me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is/2` is not a complete constraint solver. So `N is M + 1` and `M is N - 1` look to be equivalent but they are not. The first only succeeds when M is instantiated and second when N is instantiated. Have you tried your solution with indices other zero? They will not work. You can use `plus(1, M, N)` instead of either of them to get it to work. Also clause ordering matters so `plus(1, M, N)` should be before the recursive call to `nth`.

```
nth([X|_], 0, X).
nth([_|T],N,Z):- N > 0, plus(1, M, N), nth(T, M, Z).
```

If `N > 0, nth(T, M, Z), plus(1, M, N)` is your clause ordering, your program will try to satisfy `nth(T, M, Z)` first and cause an uninstantiated error at `N > 0` since M is not already instantiated.

Also neither program will work in the generative case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you pls explain/provide links to resources that explain why clause ordering matters and how it affects the program? 

Also, is using `plus (1, M, N)` a safe strategy whenever there is a confusion like this? And this should be placed before the recursive call right?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the generative case? Eg `nth([1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 2, X)`?

Comment: `nth([a, b, c, d, e], N, d)` should give you N = 3, since it is the only value with which the clause is satisfied. But in these solutions it will not work. Check `nth0` predicate and use it like `nth0(N, [a, b, c, d, e], X)` it will give you all the pairs N, X that satisfy the clause. When you use a det(semidet) predicate without giving sufficient input to iterate over all possible solutions you are using it in generative mode.

Comment: See http://cs.union.edu/~striegnk/learn-prolog-now/html/node29.html for simple example of how ordering affects execution

Comment: `plus` will work for simple additions and subtractions, but for more general arithmetic look at `clpfd` library